# determine if the open() function has opened a file or a directory?

Tags: c, file

I want to read a file with the read() function, and this is my code source :

```
char *buf;
    int bytesRead;
    int fildes;
    char path[128];
    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
    int flags = O_RDONLY;
    printf("\n%s-->Donner l'emplacement du fichier :%s ", CYAN_NORMAL, RESETCOLOR);
    scanf("%s", path);
    fildes = open(path, flags, mode);
    if(fildes == -1){
        printf("\nImpossible de lire le fichier. Réessayez plus tard. (%s)",strerror(errno));
    }else{
        while ((bytesRead = read(fildes, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0)
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I give a directory as a path the program read it, and display an empty line as if it was an empty file.

I want to read only files, and when I give a directory as a path, I want my program to display a message.

How can I know if the open() function has opened a file or a directory ?

Comment: Yous utilise un function sappelle `stat`. Il et bon pour vous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the type of path before opening:

```
struct stat statbuf;
if( stat(path,&statbuf) == 0 )
{
    if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode) )
    {
        //it's a directory
    }
    else if (S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode) )
    {
        //it's a file
    }
    else
    {
        //something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `stat` or `fstat` functions (the first one works with a path the second one with a file descriptor)  here's a function that does that job :

```
    int isDir(char* path)
{
        struct stat buff;
        stat(path , &buff);
        if((buff.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)
                return 0;
        else if ((buff.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG)
                return 1;
        else
                return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fstat) your path and check the `st_mode` attribute of the structure [struct stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) whether it is directory or a file before attempting to open it.

Example:

```
int is_dir(const char* name)
{
    struct stat st;
    if (-1 == stat(name, &st)) {
      return -1; // check errno to see what went wrong
    }
    return (int)((st.st_mode & S_IFDIR) == S_IFDIR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comme ça:

```
fildes = open(path, flags, mode);
if(fildes == -1){
    printf("\nImpossible de lire le fichier. Réessayez plus tard. (%s)",strerror(errno));
}else{
    struct stat statb;

    if (fstat(fildes, &statb) == -1)
        printf("\nImpossible de «fstat» le fichier. Réessayez plus tard. (%s)",
            strerror(errno));
    else if ((statb.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)
        printf("\nC'est un dossier, pas un fichier.");
    else
    {
        while ((bytesRead = read(fildes, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0)
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

(feel free to fix my very bad French; I don't know what the right word is for "directory", for example).

`fstat()` is probably a bit faster than `stat()`.